# Facebook API - Social Login

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I working on my app to implement social login. In development it's ok, everything is working (you can see it with my test app, 81 calls of the API) but when i try to configure my app in production, it's failed and i have an API error.

"Impossible de charger cette URL: Le domaine de cette URL n’est pas inscrit dans ceux de l’application. Pour pouvoir importer cette URL, ajoutez tous les domaines et sous-domaines de votre application au champ Domaines des paramètres de l’application."

I don't understand what i have to put in this domain field in the parameters of the app.

I've tried : recette.domain.ovh / domain.ovh / www.domain.ovh

Nothing is working...Someone can help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was very simple, i've just add the domain name www.domain.ovh and recette.domain.ovh and it's working :)

Comment: Added domains where? Please provide more informations

Comment: You have to put it into "App Domains".